# oAuth consumer for myspace not returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, httpwebresponse, myspace

I am using the following link as a base for implementing myspace oAuth consumer in my website.
http://stevenng.net/2009/03/17/using-myspace-rest-api-with-oauth-and-c/

When i use the basic oAuthBase.cs class i receive the 401 unauthorized error but when i use the updated oAuthBase.cs as mentioned by the blogger in the above post in response to a comment, the 401 error is removed but still the ResponseStream does not return anything. When i copy the request url and place it in the browser, i see the data being returned but its not workign in code. Can someone please suggest something.

Btw, for the sake of simplicity, i m using MakeRequest("/v1/users/myuserid"); instead of getting the friends.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Client_Libraries

and

http://code.google.com/p/myspaceid-csharp-sdk/